# Ignore table css class when row is clicked (Chrome)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap css for the table so the row background changes when hovered over

```
<table id="tableAppList" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
</table>
```

css:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover > td,
.table-hover tbody tr:hover > th {
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

When the row is clicked I add the "rowSelected" class to change the background colour

Typescript:

```
$("#tableAppList tr").on("click", (e: JQueryEventObject) => {
                e.preventDefault();                    
                var appName = $(e.currentTarget).find("td").eq(0).find("label").text();
                this.selectedAppRowId = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id");
                $(e.currentTarget).addClass("rowSelected");

                this.getAppUsers(appName);
            });
```

As expected the row loses it's "selected" background color when hovered over because of the table css.

So is there a way to override or ignore the table css class for the selected row?

Have tried this so far but doesn't work:

```
.rowSelected 
{
   background-color: #606060;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rowSelectedOverrideHover tr:hover > td 
{
   background-color: #606060;
}
```

Perhaps the only alternative is to not use the table-hover css class and instead add a class to the row when hovered using jQuery (a bit inefficient) which I can opt to ignore if it is selected.

Any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your rule for your selected background uses a selector with a higher [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than the selector for the hover. For example, this

```
tbody tr.rowSelected > td,
tbody tr.rowSelected > th {
   background-color: #606060;
}
```

has same specificity, so if you put it after the rule for the hover it will override it in all cases.